# Is there an alternative to using a PHP while statement inside HTML using Woody code Snippet?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, while-loop, drop-down-menu

I am using "Woody Code Snippet - Universal Snippet" with a PHP while statement inside HTML to create a dropdown . Unfortunately, the PHP While statement is breaking Elementor in my WordPress website. If I add the code to my Elementor page, it breaks Elementor. So, I am trying to find out if there is an alternate way of creating the dropdown data without using the PHP While statement.

This does not break Elementor:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <select name="formLeagueType" id="LeagueType" required>
            <option value="">Select Your League Type....</option>
        <?php //while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_LeagueType)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['league_type_id'];?>><?php echo $row1['league_name'];?></option>
        <?php //endwhile;?>
    </select>   
    <input type="submit" name="submitCAP" value="Step 2" Style = "color:white; background-color:blue" required>     
</form>
```

If I remove the "//" PHP comments, it breaks Elementor:

```
<form method='POST'>
    <select name="formLeagueType" id="LeagueType" required>
            <option value="">Select Your League Type....</option>
        <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_LeagueType)):;?>
        <option value=<?php echo $row1['league_type_id'];?>><?php echo $row1['league_name'];?></option>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </select>   
    <input type="submit" name="submitCAP" value="Step 2" Style = "color:white; background-color:blue" required>     
</form>
```

I hope that I can find an alternate way of pulling the data from the backend to populate the dropdown.

Comment: Can you define "breaks Elementor"? Does it give an error, bad formatting, library/function won't function, something else?

Comment: make a shortcode, which renders the select, then use that, using or allowing arbitrary  PHP is prone to have various issues, learn to make plugins, widgets and shortcodes then you define what PHP is run

Comment: Normally, Elementor has an option "Edit with Elementor" on the page, when the PHP comments are removed, the option disappears with only "Elementor Debugger" that referes to "Theme" points to "Template File: No Templates for condition > Astra - page.php"

Comment: I just did a test and determined the issue is with Woody Snippets. One of Woody Snippets latest updates broke the option.

Comment: If this is WordPress, you should use `wpdb` and not `mysqli`

Comment: @HowardEWould you mind explaining the statement...  'If this is WordPress, you should use wpdb and not mysqli '. Are you saying I should use 'wpdb' instead of 'mysqli'. Please forgive my ignorance in understanding your comment.

Comment: I have submitted this issue to the developers of Woody Snippet. There seems to be a number of PHP codes that are failing to work correctly.